# I have two pictureBoxes in other sizes how can i make that when i click on one pictureBox it will draw a point on the smaller pictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my code but its not working not drawing points at all on pictureBox2.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int counter;
        private int pb1mouse_x;
        private int pb1mouse_y;
        private int pbsize_x;
        private int pbsize_y;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            pbsize_x = pictureBox2.Width / pictureBox1.Width;
            pbsize_y = pictureBox2.Height / pictureBox1.Height;
            label4.Visible = false;
            label5.Visible = false;
            label6.Visible = false;
            counter = 0;
            pictureBox1.Load(@"d:\radar000075.png");


        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            label4.Visible = true;
            label4.Text = String.Format("X: {0}; Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y);
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                label5.Visible = true;
                label5.Text = String.Format("X: {0}; Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y);
                counter += 1;
                label6.Visible = true;
                label6.Text = counter.ToString();
                pb1mouse_x = e.X;
                pb1mouse_y = e.Y;
                pb1mouse_x = pb1mouse_x * pbsize_x;
                pb1mouse_y = pb1mouse_y * pbsize_y;
                pictureBox2.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red);
            var g = e.Graphics;
            g.Clear(pictureBox1.BackColor);
            g.DrawEllipse(p, new Rectangle(pb1mouse_x, pb1mouse_y, 10, 10));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply multiply by factors, i.e. smallBox.Width/largeBox.Width and smallBox.Height/largeBox.Height.  Multiply the coordinates for the larger box by those factors and it will give you coordinates for the smaller box.

**Edit:**

This is what my code looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PBoxes
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private float xFactor, yFactor;
        List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            xFactor = (float)pictureBox2.Width / pictureBox1.Width;
            yFactor = (float)pictureBox2.Height / pictureBox1.Height;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            points.Add(new PointF(e.X * xFactor, e.Y * yFactor));
            pictureBox2.Invalidate();
        }

        private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (PointF pt in points)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, pt.X, pt.Y, 3f, 3f);
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            xFactor = (float)pictureBox2.Width / pictureBox1.Width;
            yFactor = (float)pictureBox2.Height / pictureBox1.Height;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DSway can you show me please ? updated my question with the code i have now.

Comment: I just updated my question with my complete code but its not working its not drawing anything on pictureBox2. I gues im wrong with the code. Can you show me please how to fix it ?

Comment: I did smallBox.Width/largeBox.Width and smallBox.Height/largeBox.Height but you cant divide the small one by the big one.